# What is the danger of losing the password from the android keystore (.jks) and password from the key?

Tags: android, passwords, keystore

I accidentally gave the release signature automation files to customers:

```
build.gradle

storeFile file("*.jks")
        storePassword "***"
        keyAlias "***"
        keyPassword "***"
```

The keystore file is still only mine.

1. How dangerous is this situation?
2. What can you do with passwords without having the key itself?
3. Can I safely change the passwords for the vault and the key?
4. After changing the password, I can publish the application in the market and users will not suffer?

Comment: Once I lost my key, for the next update, the appstore (local one, not google play), refuses to accept it as a new update package for the existing app, then I had to submit the update as a new app, and since there were some users who had bought the older versions, and could not get the new update for free, the situation became pretty awkward!

Answer (score 1):

The password allow to decrypt the private key of the signing certificate contained in the keystore so it can be used

Without the keystore, an attacker can not do anything with your passwords. Just change them and continue using the key